# VS Code extension: Automatically updating file imports on rename

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to automatically update the file imports when using the vscode rename api for an extension?

```
vscode.workspace.fs.rename(fileUri, newFileUri);
```

Basically looking to hook into the behavior provided by the setting `typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled` when you manually rename a file

I realize that this isn't in the public api, but I was wondering if there was even a way to hook into it in a more hacky way? If not, what's the best way to go about solving this issue?

```
vscode.workspace.fs.rename(fileUri, newFileUri);
```

but this does not trigger the updating of the imports

Comment: your language provider needs to support this

Comment: The language I'm using is Typescript, so the language provider does support this, my question is pertaining to how I can utilize that existing functionality programmatically in my custom extension

Comment: `vscode.workspace.fs.rename` is just a wrapper for the `OS::rename` system call if the workspace is on the local disk, try to find what command is called when TS detects a file move and if it accepts arguments